# Why did I get negative points for an answer?

Tags: discussion

The other day I posted in this section and received +20 reptuation. Today, I logged in and noticed I had received -2 for the answer I provided. My question is, how do you receive negative points? I had 2 "thumbs up", now I have one. Does this mean if the OP, or whoever, decided they really didn't favor my response and took it back, but it only took away 2 reputation and left me with 8 because of their original "thumbs up"?

Also, not sure if this is the right area to be asking this question...

Comment: More information is available on the [Reputation help page](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you click on the Score Number [not the up or down votes button]; this will show the split of up vote and down vote. Plus in your User profile under reputation tab it would show the details of when the answer got upvoted or downvoted or upvote removed.

Comment: @Dheer The feature that lets you see the up and down vote split is only available for users with a rep of 1k or higher.

Comment: @BenMiller Thanks didn't realize it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone downvoted your answer.  That accounts for the (-2) reputation and also for the reduced number of "thumbs up".  So, based on what you said, you have two votes up and one vote down.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know if it was the same fella.

Comment: Must be a different person - If someone retracted an upvote, you would have lost the 10 points that you got from the original vote.  Also there's a time limit after which votes cannot be revoked unless the question /answer has been edited. @lucasdavis500